# signed_extension in c

Tags: c

I have tried the below program and getting the output as 72. I could not understand how it outputs as 72.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=0x27ea4d72;
    char x=a;
    printf("%x",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined Behavior.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to know.

Comment: The value assigned looks like dependent on endianness, not sure though

Comment: @Shash316: That wouldn't make sense. You need the least significant part when converting from int to char.

Comment: Quote from ANSI C Manual : "In simple assignment, the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value of the object referred to by the left
operand". In this particular example only 0x72 got assigned to char variable, So I thought may be last bytes got assigned.

Comment: Because you truncate 0x27ea4d72 to a char, i.e. 0x72, and then print it, i.e. 72. The question is what did you expect? Also, what is the reference to "signed_extension" in the title?

Comment: @Code Monkey: not if `char` is `unsigned char` (in which case you are guaranteed that the result is reduced modulo 2^CHAR_BITS).

Comment: Why are you assigning an int to a char? What are you trying to achieve by that?

Comment: int a=0x27ea4def;     
 char x=a;     I changed my code from 72 to ef and i'm getting the output as ffffffef.It takes the LSB values.. why is it taking the 2 values 72 in the previous example and why is it giving me ffffffef when changed as a=0x27ea4def.

Comment: why is the ffffffef gets printed when modifies as int a=0x27eadef?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C standard:

> 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer
>      type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new
>      type, it is unchanged.
> 2. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>      repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>      can be represented in the new type until the
>      value is in the range of the new type.
> 3. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be
>      represented in it; the result is
>      implementation-defined.

The conversion falls into case #3 because the values are signed. So the result is implementation-defined.

However, for the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long a = 0x27ea4d72UL;
    unsigned char x = a;
    printf("%x",x);
    return 0;
}
```

The conversion falls into case #2 in which case the standard basically says that the result would be 0x27ea4d72 % (UCHAR_MAX+1). Where UCHAR_MAX is 255 (most common case), you'd get 0x72.

Answer (score 3):

Since `int` is normally wider than `char`, `char x=a;` truncates the value of `int` being assigned.

From ["The New C Standard" book](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/dmjones/cbook1_0a.pdf):

> In the case of conversions to narrower integer types, the generated machine code may depend on what
>   operation performed on the result of the cast. **In the case of assignment the appropriate least-signiﬁcant
>   bits of the unconverted operand are usually stored.** For other operators implementations often zero out the
>   nonsigniﬁcant bits (performing a bitwise-AND operation is often faster than a remainder operation) and for
>   signed types sign extend the result